# How to find the sum of two separate items of data in python, separately?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

How can I restart the program?
I am trying to find the sum of the first set of data in the first loop and then the sum of the data in the second loop alone, but the sum in the last loop calculates the sum of the data in that loop and the one before.  What mistake did I make?

```
import random, time

#Variables
die1 = 0
die2 = 0
goal = 0
tries1 = 0
tries2 = 0
sum = 0
#Asking for the player's names
player1 = input("What is your name, player1?")
player2 = input("What is your name, player2?")

#The "goal"
goal = random.randrange(5) + 1
print("The goal is:", goal)

while die1 != goal:
   die1 = random.randrange(5) + 1
   print(player1, "Your roll is:", die1)
   tries1 = tries1 + 1
   sum = sum + die1
print(sum)
while die2 != goal:
    die2 = random.randrange(5) + 1
    print(player2, "Your roll is:", die2)
    tries2 = tries2 + 1
    sum = sum + die2
print(sum)
```

Comment: What is the value of `sum` before the first loop? What's its value after the first loop? And how would you normally change the value of a variable?

Comment: the value of sum before the first loop is 0. and after the first loop it would depend on how many times the random numbers are generated. Could you please tell me how to change the value to help make the sums in the second loop correct, please. :)

Comment: you can use another variable `sum2` for second sum(if you need both sum for latter codes). Or reset `(sum=0)` before second loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing re-initializing sum to 0 after the first loop.

Comment: What if I want to print out both sums, how can I do that?

Comment: @Johnny - either store the sums in a list or in different variables if you want both

Comment: okay thank you! And would you guys no How I can put in the option to restart the program?

Comment: would you guys know How I can put in the option to restart the program?

Comment: @Johnny that's a different question.  but the typical way is a while loop and prompting the user at the end whether they want to go around again or not.

Comment: Thanks @RyanHaining, could you show me how would it work on my program, please! :)

Comment: `choice = 'y'` `while choice != 'n'`: <entire program> `choice = input("would you like to go again?: ").lower()[0]`  Think about it

Comment: Thanks @RyanHaining !! I'll try it and see how it goes!

Comment: @RyanHaining , it doesn't work the way it should, do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not an explanation of the problem.  [it does work](http://pastebin.com/zEE0W358)